# Origin of the Expression: "Yes, Harriet"

Tags: idioms, slang, history

When I was a child (in the 1970s) when my mother asked my father to do something that he had already planned to do, he would say "Yes, Harriet".  Can anyone tell me where this expression "Yes, Harriet" came from?

Comment: Sounds like mock politeness in a reference to the perfect marriage of TV couple Ozzie and Harriet. Yes, Dear, you are right, Dear. What the real couple was like is anyone's guess.

Comment: Probably Ozzie. Cannot find reference but an old radio play, Suspense or other show, called *After Christmas* had the hen pecked husband plotting to do away with his wife. All along he, Paul Frees, answering her "Yes, Hermione." with increasing menace. It was performed on *Alfred Hitchcock Presents* but was never was so scary as it was with radio's Paul Frees.